# Why is The Doctor forgetting things in Season 9?

Tags: doctor-who

It seems that the twelfth Doctor is a bit absent minded, and seems to be forgetting lots of random things.  For instance, he has forgotten:

- The umbrella stand
- Various names
- The person who first wore his face

Why?  Has something happened to his memory or is this normal?

Comment: When you are 2000 years old, your head needs to manage lots of memories...

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 But this isn't common for the Doctor. Plus, based on Ashieldr losing her memories (and the Doctor's reaction to it) and Donna nearly dying, we know TimeLord brains are much "bigger" and very different to human ones.

Comment: @LordVoldemort This is common. I have listened these lots of times from the previous Doctors: "I am missing something" "Oh yes, this means..." "How can I forget this"

Comment: Lots of times his memory reflexes aren't quick..

Comment: “He forgot umbrella stand” — eh?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Though not this season, Clara asked 12 where the umbrella stand was, and he couldn't remember.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: okay. Was that in ’Listen’?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't recall which episode, but I can picture the scene.  She was entering the TARDIS with an umbrella, and the stand to place it was missing.  It was definitely in Season 8, but cannot be sure of the episode.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Are you sure you're not thinking of "Hide" from Series 7? "CLARA: Hey. You need a place to keep this [an umbrella].
DOCTOR: I've got one. Or I had one. I think I had one. Look around. See if you find it. Did I have one? Am I going mad?"

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, that must be it.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, when The Doctor regenerates, he goes through some big, different issues, which vary from incarnation to incarnation. For instance, Nine was concerned with his ears, Ten was in a coma for most of his first story, and Eleven blew up the T.A.R.D.I.S. For Twelve it was amnesia.

Remember when he had just regenerated, he had forgotten even how to fly the TARDIS ("The Time of The Doctor"), so it is reasonable to accept that he would forget details like where he had seen his face before, or the clockwork droids in "Deep Breath".

Then, once his regeneration had settled he started to remember, but now there's a catch: He doesn't always care. He meets people, and then "deletes" them from his mind, like in "Last Christmas". That's the cynicism I like in this Doctor, that hadn't been seen perhaps since the first one.

Comment: "*Eleven blew up the T.A.R.D.I.S.*" - I thought it was River and the Silence who blew up the TARDIS?

Comment: I meant Ten's regeneration into Eleven, at the end of "The End of Time".